# Why are my times screwed up on some devices but fine on others?

Tags: icalendar

I have an icalendar I generate via PHP so people can download the latest schedule to their phones.  It works great except that the game times are off by 6 hours on my iPhone.  The game time is perfectly fine displaying on Windows calendar.

I've tried playing with the timezones and times but cannot get them to be equal on all platforms.

The calendar is viewable at:
webcal://cal.outbackthunder.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dawson,
your ics file at http://cal.outbackthunder.com has the event dates specified in 'local' or 'floating' times.

So the importing app will probably make the events be that time in it's timezone. 8am is 8am in all timezones (think of a travellers alarm clock - where they want to wake at 8m no matter the timezone they are in, vs a reminder to call their partner at 8am in the home timezone, where they'd then want it to adjust to the traveling timezone.)

Either add a Z and issue date-times in UTC, or add the TZID identifer of the timezone.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5.

See these examples in the spec:

Example:  The following represents July 14, 1997, at 1:30 PM in New
York City in each of the three time formats, using the "DTSTART"
property.

```
   DTSTART:19970714T133000                   ; Local time
   DTSTART:19970714T173000Z                  ; UTC time
   DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:19970714T133000
                                             ; Local time and time
                                             ; zone reference
```

Also try running your ics file through as many validators as you can find if you want the general public to be able to use the url. They tend to report slightly differently.  EG: one says of http://cal.outbackthunder.com

> DATE-TIME value in [DTSTAMP] must be specified in UTC time

> Property [ORGANIZER] must be specified once

Comment: Turns out, I had the right idea.  All the times listed were in my local time so I had subtracted the 6 hours to make it UTC (which I found is required most of the time).  However, when I defined a constant in PHP that I could use multiple times in the PHP date function to get the format.  I added the "Z" in that constant which in turn translates to the timezone as PHP Date transforms it.  Moved the Z to a location where it will stay a Z; fix the errors on my calendar as you suggested and they seem to be synced with the right times.  Thanks @anmari!!